# Loop through array adding all previous values to current value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, addition, cumulative-sum

I wish to loop through an array adding the previous value to the current one. This is my latest attempt, but does not output the desired result

```
$array = array(
    "myKeyName"   => 3,
    "anotherName" => 8,
    "aKeyName"    => 12,
    "keyName"     => 6,
    "anotherKey"  => 34
    );

$setItems = array();

$i = 1;

foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $setItems['item'.$i] = $val+$val;
    $i++;
};

print_r($setItems);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array ( [item1] => 6 [item2] => 16 [item3] => 24 [item4] => 12 [item5] => 68 )
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Array ( [item1] => 3 [item2] => 11 [item3] => 23 [item4] => 29 [item5] => 63 )
```

I understand why I am getting the current output, I just don;t know how to change it get get the desired output efficiently. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds a little like homework btw, is it? In any case, you'll have to keep track of the total of the previous values in the array and add that to the current value of the array in each iteration.

Comment: This isn't homework. years since I was at school. I'm a newbie.

Comment: @StevenPHP Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    "myKeyName"   => 3,
    "anotherName" => 8,
    "aKeyName"    => 12,
    "keyName"     => 6,
    "anotherKey"  => 34
    );

$setItems = array();

$i = 1;
$previous = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $setItems['item'.$i] = $val+$previous;
    $previous += $val;
    $i++;
};
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried something very similar. Where you have `+=` it tired `.=`. Thanks!